# Ruby On Rails - When I hit back I only see Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, render, reload, back

When going back on my latest app I can only see the code from one of my javascript files that I've included in the assets/javascripts?

If I then try to hit reload it renders the page as I would like it to be.

I just noticed that the same thing occur when I hit forward on my application.

Something with the cache?